# Doing an udev rule at boot time

Tags: systemd, udev

I have a service that I want to run, only after udev has set the correct permissions on device files.

This seems to go wrong at boot time:
My service is started, with the `/dev/hidraw0` file permissions not yet set.

My service is defined as:

```
# cat /lib/systemd/system/turboledz.service 
[Unit]
Description=Turbo LEDz service
After=systemd-udevd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
User=daemon
ExecStart=/usr/bin/turboledzd
KillMode=control-group

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I can see its dependency:

```
# systemctl list-dependencies turboledz
turboledz.service
● ├─system.slice
● └─sysinit.target
●   ├─apparmor.service
●   ├─dev-hugepages.mount
●   ├─dev-mqueue.mount
●   ├─keyboard-setup.service
●   ├─kmod-static-nodes.service
●   ├─plymouth-read-write.service
●   ├─plymouth-start.service
●   ├─proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount
●   ├─setvtrgb.service
●   ├─sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-config.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-debug.mount
●   ├─sys-kernel-tracing.mount
○   ├─systemd-ask-password-console.path
○   ├─systemd-binfmt.service
○   ├─systemd-boot-system-token.service
○   ├─systemd-hwdb-update.service
●   ├─systemd-journal-flush.service
●   ├─systemd-journald.service
○   ├─systemd-machine-id-commit.service
●   ├─systemd-modules-load.service
○   ├─systemd-pstore.service
●   ├─systemd-random-seed.service
●   ├─systemd-sysctl.service
●   ├─systemd-sysusers.service
●   ├─systemd-timesyncd.service
●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
●   ├─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
●   ├─systemd-udev-trigger.service
●   ├─systemd-udevd.service
●   ├─systemd-update-utmp.service
●   ├─cryptsetup.target
●   ├─local-fs.target
●   │ ├─-.mount
●   │ ├─boot-efi.mount
●   │ ├─mnt-farm0.mount
●   │ ├─mnt-farm1.mount
●   │ ├─mnt-farm2.mount
●   │ ├─mnt-farm3.mount
●   │ ├─mnt-farm4.mount
●   │ ├─mnt-farm5.mount
○   │ ├─systemd-fsck-root.service
●   │ └─systemd-remount-fs.service
●   ├─swap.target
●   │ └─swapfile.swap
●   └─veritysetup.target
```

The permission should have been taken care of, with this rule:

```
# cat /lib/udev/rules.d/70-turboledz.rules 
# Make Vendor "Arduino LLC", Product "Arduino Micro" accessible for non-root users.
# Note: BUS 1 is USB.

SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8037", MODE="0666"

KERNEL=="hidraw*", ATTRS{busnum}=="1", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{idProduct}=="8037", MODE="0666"
```

Normally, this rule properly sets the permission when I plug in the device.

But at boot time, it does not seem to get run?

Do all udev rules run during boot?

**UPDATE:**

I see that eventually the rule does get run, as after boot, when I log into the machine, I see the correct permissions.

It appears that the rule is just applied to late for my service.

**OS:** Ubuntu 21.10

**CPU:** i5-11600K

**Kernel:** Linux i7 5.13.0-22-generic

**Systemd:** 248.3-1ubuntu8

Comment: Could you test if `sudo update-initramfs -u` helps?